# How does one get tab-completion in gsettings from zsh?

Tags: gsettings, zsh, auto-completion

I notice that when using the bash shell (for example) the `gsettings` command has tab-completion; but when I use the Z shell (zsh) `gsettings` has no tab-completion. How can I enable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The zsh-comp-gsettings plugin](https://github.com/jmatsuzawa/zsh-comp-gsettings) gives you that.

Just follow the instructions on the repo:

1. Download the [_gsettings file here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jmatsuzawa/zsh-comp-gsettings/master/_gsettings), and
2. Move (`sudo mv`) it into one of your `$fpath` directories (I put it in `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Zsh/_gsettings`).

Simple as that!